# WIX MSI Installed from Windows Service

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, burn, wix3

I am working on self installing software.  There is a windows service that is running and can be notified that there is a software update.  At that time, it will download my burn exe and do a process.start to silently install it.  The installer works as expected except for one issue - the services it installs won't start due to a logon failure.  If I change the service password in services, the service will start, so I am confident the issue resolves around the service account password.  Here's the rub - if I run the exact same installer on the exact same machine from the interactive desktop (logged on user), it works!

Here is one of the services I install:

```
<ServiceInstall
    Id="DataAcquisitionInstaller"
    Type="ownProcess"
    Name="DataAcquisitionService"
    DisplayName="Data Acquisition Service"
    Description="Handles all data acquisitions"
    Start="demand"
    Account="[SERVICEACCOUNTUSERID]"
    Password="[SERVICEACCOUNTPASSWORD]"
    ErrorControl="normal"
>
<util:PermissionEx
  User="[SERVICEACCOUNTUSERID]"
  GenericAll="yes"
  ServiceChangeConfig="yes"
  ServiceEnumerateDependents="yes"
  ChangePermission="yes"
  ServiceInterrogate="yes"
  ServicePauseContinue="yes"
  ServiceQueryConfig="yes"
  ServiceQueryStatus="yes"
  ServiceStart="yes"
  ServiceStop="yes" />
    <ServiceConfig DelayedAutoStart="yes" OnInstall="yes" OnReinstall="yes"/>
</ServiceInstall>
```

I have verified in the log that SERVICEACCOUNTUSERID and SERVICEACCOUNTPASSWORD are correct.  The only difference I can see in the log is this:

**When installing from service:**

> MSI (s) (30:80) [10:05:28:905]: Executing op:
>   ServiceInstall(Name=DataAcquisitionService,DisplayName=Data
>   Acquisition Service,ImagePath="C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\xxx\xxx\Services\DataAcquisitionService.exe",ServiceType=16,StartType=3,ErrorControl=1,,Dependencies=[~]**[~],TagId=0**,StartName=.\test,Password=**********,Description=Handles
>   all data acquisitions,**SecurityDescriptor=BinaryData**,)

**When installing from the interactive desktop as the logged in user**

> MSI (s) (44:E8) [09:45:57:518]: Executing op:
>   ServiceInstall(Name=DataAcquisitionService,DisplayName=Data
>   Acquisition Service,ImagePath="C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\xxx\xxx\Services\DataAcquisitionService.exe",ServiceType=16,StartType=3,ErrorControl=1,,Dependencies=[~],,StartName=.\test,Password=**********,Description=Handles
>   all data acquisitions,,)

What does this mean --> "SecurityDescriptor=BinaryData"?  Is that what is causing my issue and if so, how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: You are not granting the service account logon type 5 access.

Comment: Is this what you are referring to - LogonAsService (and even local admin rights)?  I am doing that...

        <util:User Id="DataAcquisitionInstallerServiceUser" CreateUser="no" FailIfExists="no" UpdateIfExists="yes" Name="[SERVICEACCOUNTUSERID]" LogonAsService="yes">
          <util:GroupRef Id="AdminGroup"/>
        </util:User>

Comment: Yup, I'm out of ideas. Maybe try the WIX user mailing list at http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/mailinglist/

Comment: Just though of something, when you install it in an unattended fashion, `InstallUISequence` is not run, only `InstallExecuteSequence`. Are you deriving the password for the account somehow only during `InstallUISequence` which would indicate why a manual, attended installation works? If that is the case, the unset property will be blank when you access it during the service installation.

Comment: The property is actually passed a command line property to the MSI.  As I said, in the log, I see the property being set to the correct value.  Thanks for the time on the mailing list - will try them.